# Confused between Jahia and dotcms as a java CMS

Tags: content-management-system, liferay, dotcms, jahia

Which is better for web content management purposed only?
The website requirements include a user discussion forum and a poll survey with a good search facility and also needs a good SEO tool. The site should also load faster and should be easy to edit contents.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this thread. It explains what Dotcms does well and not so well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751891/java-based-cms-with-restful-service-api-to-access-content

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to Jahia, but dotCMS can do everything you're asking for. Below are some links that should help you self evaluate dotCMS. I also would point out that dotCMS is more of a platform (makes a great user experience platform UXP) than an off-the-shelf solution and because of this your requirements might take a little work to setup and get running. With that being said, your finished product should meet your exact needs.

Site Search (uses ElasticSearch)
http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/SiteSearch

Performance Report
http://dotcms.com/aw/performance-report

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Jahia should be able to handle these request. I am the opposite if Fish and have experience with jahia. Jahia does have a forum and poll component's both available as open source so you can modify the code when you require to.

What I like about jahia (among many other things) is that editing content is straight forward and very easy to for non technical persons. ofcourse it has all the permissions in place for all content so you can set it up in such a way that you don't have to be afraid that the non technical persons will mess-up a website.

Performance of Jahia, even without fancy caching proxies is very good and it can run on low resource VM's, just if you want to start small. I am using them on small Linode machines without any issues

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with Dotcms, but basic forums, polls, search, and SEO are all freely available as Jahia modules.  The forums are certainly not as good as a standalone like Vanilla, but they are simple to add and administrate.  Search is good and requires little configuration, and anything more than basic SEO is going to be custom work.